# IMAP attachments

Tags: php, mysql, backup, imap

I'm creating a script in PHP, which's job is to backup an IMAP server to a MySQL database.

My question now is:

If an email has an attachment, is that attachment embedded in the email itself or is it a separate file on the server?

My reason for asking, is:

Can i save the header info in a MySQL db, and thereby extract the attachments in a given email, or do i have to download the attachments to the backup server?

Kind regards,

Frederik Krogh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attechment is part of the mail body. It usually is not stored in a different file than the email. Email clients split the body of the email using the mentioned MIME types.

You can read it up in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045 (and the following RFCs)

Answer (score 0):

IMAP will let you have it both ways.  By inspecting the bodystructure and using part fetches, you can either get them separately, or you can fetch the entire email (with it's embedded attachments) all at once.